# Select box option breakout in Chrome

Tags: html, ajax, forms, google-chrome, select

I'm populating a select box using Ajax

```
<select size="5" style="width: 500px" name="Lessons_Select[]" id="Lessons_Select"  multiple>
</select>
```

The line that populates the select looks like this

```
document.getElementById("Lessons_Select").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

No issue in Firefox
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy2n4.jpg

In Chrome (Version 38.0.2125.111) I am seeing this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IoCt.jpg

The options bust out of the select box and go mad down the page.

They do not however go past the closing tag of the select box
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljzW4.jpg

So why do you think this is happening in Chrome, I've tried everything I can think of.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

In a linked stylesheet

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
```

popped off the comment and now all is well

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:hidden;` should work.

```
#Lessons_Select { 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```